# What is the Python equivalent of application & session scope variables?

Tags: python, session, scope, web-applications

Recently started on python, wondered what the equivalent object was for storing session & application scope data?

I'm using Google App Engine too so if it has any extra features (can't seem to find any immediate references myself) that would be useful

Comment: anything other than the GAE datastore obviously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're talking about a web session, used to retain state between http requests. Python is a general programming language and by itself doesn't contain the concept of a session.

However most different python web frameworks have session implementations. Which one are you using? I've linked to the session documentation on some python web frameworks:

- [mod_python](http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/pyapi-sess.html)
- [django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#topics-http-sessions)
- [paste](http://pythonpaste.org/modules/session.html)
- [web.py](http://webpy.org/sessions)

Comment: Well, it helps if you know the terms "application scope" and "session scope" are from Java's JSP technology, which is web programming.

Comment: yeah sorry for not being explicit - I thought maybe it had a built in way of working with sessions.  Datastore it is